# Calling a stored procedure in SQL Server from python with two parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

So I am currently trying to connect a stored procedure in sql server to a python program. I connect to the server fine and can grab tables but when I try to run my stored procedure I get a "This result does not return rows" error. Here is the code I am using to call the stored procedure:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sal

engine = sal.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://{}:{}@{}/{}?driver={}'.format(username,password,server,database,driver_2))


previous_days_start_value = 1
previous_days_end_value = 10
sql_query = sal.text("EXEC clk.get_codes_pdf :previous_days_start, :previous_days_end")


pdf_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql_query, engine, params={"previous_days_start":previous_days_start_value, "previous_days_end":previous_days_end_value})
```

This is basically the stored procedure I am calling:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [gen].[get_codes] 
@previous_days_start bigint, @previous_days_end bigint
AS
BEGIN TRY
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select * from #Table;
END Try
```

And when I execute this inside of sql I do get a table. I can execute this like:

```
exec gen.get_codes 30,10
```

And the table prints out perfectly.

Any help would be very appreciated

I want to return the temp table from my stored procedure. I have tested the stored procedure using:

```
exec gen.get_codes 30,10
```

Where I do get a table in return. I also tried adding

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

But I still could not get a table returned. It seems to make the connection but then no table is returned into my dataframe

Comment: You do realize the stored procedure you're calling in python is not the same one you referenced below, right? In your python code you're calling `clk.get_codes_pdf` and in your later examples, you're calling `gen.get_codes`

Comment: The code in your "basically what your calling" proc also references a temp table that is never declared or populated. It's impossible to diagnose a stored procedure which isn't even valid sql.

Comment: Yes asking for data from #Table will fail as it wont exist it session level and you have not created the #Table. Also maybe call it something more than #Table e.g #TableOfCodes. Surely you must have an actual table to query without the #(hash). Call the stored proc in SSMS and see EXEC [gen].[get_codes] 1, 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas [read_sql_query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query) is for reading an SQL result-set into a Pandas DataFrame.

The error that you're getting suggests that your stored-procedure isn't intended to return a result-set. Using the [SqlAlchemy engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine) (the `engine` variable in your code sample) directly would be more suitable.

As per the comments, you should also check that stored-procedure that you're testing is the same one that the code is trying to run.